# How to validate an empty textField that can accepts only integers?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote like this; but it fails to integer only textfields

```
if(textField_1.getText().length()==0)  

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter text in textfield");
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, when you are validating user input in Java, you will want to check for both null and empty string values.  To check String objects for equality, you must use the .equals() method (not the == operator).  Thus, a check for an empty String value might look something like this:

```
if ( val == null || val.trim().equals( "" ) )
{
    // handle empty String case
}
else
{
    // handle non-empty String case
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: indeed, if you check `String`s for equality, the `equals` method is the way to go. But the `length` method is very ok to check if a `String` is empty. Also, the `getText` method does not return `null` `Strings`.

Comment: @user1213523 i am glad that i could help, you can accept my answer by clicking on right sign just below the vote mark.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(textField_1.getText().isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter text in textfield");  
}
```

Comment: I think u had no need to add description of urself. Thanks for an easy solution though. :)